# How do I obtain Linux distribution version in java

Tags: java, linux, operating-system, jvm, linux-distro

I'm writing a spring boot app where I am required to fetch the Linux distribution version within a function.
For example, if my app is running on an Ubuntu-16.04 machine, then I would like to know this version within my method. Or if I'm working on CentOS 6.9, then the method should return this.

I found that jvm stores some system properties which has os name, version and architecture. But the problem is that I have no way of determining the distribution from the kernel version number.

There is also the method of reading /etc/os-release, but this file is not present in older versions of centos.
I also found that /proc/version is not always present.

Is there a generic way to obtain this distribution value?

Comment: No generic way. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script

Comment: You must ask the operating system by invoking commands.